# Does match_parent make it same as parent, or just fill remaining space?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just to clarify some misconception.

But is Android's `match_parent` property making the target view just filling the rest of the parent's available space,

or is it literally "matching parent" regardless of whether or not doing so will overflow the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the behavior of `layout_*` params like `layout_height` and `layout_width` depends on how the parent `ViewGroup` decides to handle them. You might create a view group that ignores `match_parent`, for instance.

Practically, it is common for `match_parent` to mean *match the parent dimension*. Regardless of whether doing so will overflow the screen.